# Find all usages of an ASP.NET MVC View with Resharper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I don't know if I am being daft but I can't find a way of finding all usages of a View (cshtml file) with VS and Resharper. The view could be full or partial. If someone could help me out this would be useful for a new project I am working on!

Comment: Wouldn't find in files do this simply enough?

Comment: It would but then that still means you have to look closely through the results to pick out the right ones. I would've thought Resharper had a nicer option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have ReSharper installed:

1. Select the View file from Solution Explorer
2. With you keyboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. OR, Right click on the View and select *Find Usages Advanced...*

   - [image: Find Usages Advanced...]
3. This brings you a window. Select all the checkboxes from *Find* column, and select solution from *Scope* column, click <kbd>Find</kbd>

   - [image: Search Properties]
4. This will bring you a list of usages, in *Find result* window.

   - [image: Find Results]

Comment: After reading this I right-clicked on the file and realised there was a Find Usages option there that I'd missed before. Using Find Usages Advanced was useful though as it also came up with places where the file was loaded.

Comment: I am using VS Enterprise 2017 with ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.1 and none of the contextual `Find Usages` menus popped for me on right-click. However, hitting the keyboard command brought up the window.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the view (or partial) and select "Find Usages"